# Spring Surf service index or console authentication needed

Tags: authentication, indexing, explorer, alfresco

At work we have an installed Alfresco Explorer, and as we discovering the new possibilities of Spring Surf Web Scripts we trying to reach the **/service/console** or **/service/index** so we can manage web scripts, enabling JavaScript debugger, etc.

However to reach that URL it needs an authentication, but it doesn't accept the user/pass what we using for logging in to the explorer web app.

As we didn't find nothing about that [in the documentation](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts),
we have to ask it: anybody figured that out what type of authentication does the service index need?

Comment: Do you have some sort of custom authentication in place? And are you sending the credentials of an administrator?

Comment: We configured up a remote Alfresco server for authentication in      $CATALINA_HOME/lib/alfresco/web-extension/share-config-custom.xml with a config>remote>endpoint node. That's why the Alfresco Explorer can authenticate us, so it's working. Of course that's why we don't understand this situation, because we tried all kind of credentials I think. Maybe to reach those pages we need to do furthermore configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/service/?` is only accessible by the admin user.

Comment: Okay it turned out the admin user wasn't the admin... Our problem is solved, thanks.